# What {do / does} this and that have in common?" -- which?

Tags: grammatical-number, do-support

Example:

> What **does** beer and wine have in common?

or

> What **do** beer and wine have in common?

I've seen them both being used, the first form being more frequent, but I think the second form sounds more correct, although I can't be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do beer and wine have in common?

is the question form of

> Beer and wine have __ in common.

The subject of the question is the conjunct 'beer and wine', so the auxiliary verb *DO* takes the form for 3d person plural: *do*.

Answer (score -3):

The correct one is "What does beer and wine have in common?", because you use does with he / she / it  and do with I / you / we / they. You can read more about it [here](http://www.grammar.cl/Present/Do_Does.htm)

Comment: Incorrect.  The common feature is singular.